# angularjs - page refresh, login app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to learn angularjs and now I am trying to make a register/login app and when the user is logged, he can see some other stuff.
I created array with two users and they are default.
When i register someone new, i login, i see the stuff, everythig is fine.
BUT, when i reload the page, i have again the old two users I already put in the array.
I run in on the localhost.
Why is this happening and how to, when i register someone new and when i reload page, to have new users? Would this happen if i lunch it online?
Hope some of you understood me.

Comment: are you maintaining valid session in the cookie? what are the cookie variables before and after page refresh to identify user.

Comment: i don't have cookies...

Comment: the app recognizes users from array that has objects(eg. array[0]: {"username": "max", "password": "maxmax"}

Comment: how you are restoring users array upon refresh?

Comment: Use cookies or localstorage to save the login state and you will be fine.

Comment: well, this is what i am wondering myself and google :D I am not doing it, i just register someone new, the function push it to the array and that's all. When i refresh the page, i have just two default users (i hardcoded them in the array)..